# textview inside a scrollview ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, uitextview

I am new in IOS programming, I have a tableview, when I Select an item in the table pulls up a detail view. The detail view has title, picture, and at the bottom a textview. All those items are inside a scrollview. I want the whole page to scroll not just the text. The problem is that the textview is scrollable, so I have 2 scrolls, one for the main scroll of the view, and the second one is for the text, what I need is to combine the two scrolls, it means I want when I scroll the view, the text immediately scrolls with it.

this is a screenshot about the view:

[image]

and the scrolling is disabled:

[image]

this is after updating the height constraint

[image]

this is a screenshot of the scrollview properties

[image]

the code is:

```
        NSString *text =[[jsonResults objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"content"];

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    [self.detailTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailTextView.frame.origin.x,self.detailTextView.frame.origin.y,textSize.width,textSize.height)];

    [self.detailTextView setText:text];
scroll.ContentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

Thank You alot,

Answer (score 3):

try like this,

In your case do one this set the textview frame dynamically based on the text  and disable the scrolling of textView .and add textview to scrollview.

[image]

deselect scrolling Enabled of the textview.

Comment: @CarinaM:have you tried like this?

Comment: yes, I turned off the scroll of text view, but still the text doesn't fit the content.

Comment: means some of the text is missed in textview?

Comment: set textview frame correctly means related to text.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In your case since the height of the UITextView is less than the height of the Text , hence it is showing scrolling .

```
UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc] init];

NSString *text = @"Your Text Here";

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:YourFontSize]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MaximumWidthForTextView, MaximumHeightForTextView) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x,textView.frame.origin.y,textSize.width,textSize.height)];

[textView setText:text];
[self.scrollView addSubview:textView];

float scrollViewContentHeight = textView.frame.origin.y+textView.frame.size.height+20;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,scrollViewContentHeight)];
```

By doing this your textview would not be showing scrolling anymore . Now second problem is about scrolling in UIScrollView . In order to introduce scrolling in UIScrollView you need to set the content size of the scrollview .
eg:-

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake:(320 , 600 )];
```

In the following example where i have set the content size as 320,600 , the scrollview will show the property of scrolling since the content height of the scrollview is greater than the screen height (screen size in case of iphone 4s - (320,480));

Comment: hi, i used what you said, but sill not working, should i do something else in the storyboard attributes???

Comment: please can u check the screenshots above? 
thank you a lot

Comment: where are you setting the contentSize of the UIScrollView?

Comment: in the code, I put the syntax you gave me

Comment: In the screen shot above I can see that you also have implemented the height constraint for TextView using NSLayoutRelationEqual (==) , changes the following realtional operator to NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual (>=) , this might work for you :)

Comment: the height constraint is updated to NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual (>=) 
but still not working, check the screenshot please

Comment: I updated my answer with the screenshot for the properties to be set for UIScrollView , try it :)

Comment: the same properties are set, I sent you a screenshot please check :(, am gonna out of my mind

Comment: i also post the code you gave me

Comment: I think the problem in your case is AutoLayout , I implemented the same without AutoLayout and it is working fine . So the solution for your problem is to create UITextView runtime rather than creating it using Interface Builder . I am Updating my above code . please check :)

Comment: what do you mean by AutoLAYOUT? what should i correct?

Comment: When you are adding TextView to your view using Interface Builder some additional constraits are getting implemented on them which are not allowing the textview to set frame runtime . So I suggested you not to add UITextView using Interface Builder . You add the UITextview runtime (programmatically) as explained in my answer .

Answer (score 0):

To your

**I want the whole page to scroll not just the text**

```
 1)It will happen only if the contentSize of your view is larger than the screen size
```

e.g( if the screen is 420 and your content is something near 600 then the scrollview will scroll)

**I want when I scroll the view, the text immediately scrolls with it.**

```
2) If the content of the text inside your UITextView is more than the height of the UITextView then automatically your textView will scroll
```